# OnServerClick not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, click

The event is simply not firing, what am I missing?

Code for the button:

```
<input type="button" class="button hide" id="savetext" style="float:right;" value="Hello" runat="server" OnServerClick="savetext_Click"/>
```

and the code that is generated (ie. when opened in a browser and the source is viewed) is this:

```
<input onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$savetext','')" name="ctl00$Main$savetext" type="button" id="savetext" style="float:right;" class="button hide" value="Save to text" />
```

I've got `<pages clientIDMode="Static" />` in `web.config` but the name and generated onclick event are prefixed despite that.

Server side code:

```
Protected Sub savetext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

To be clear, my goal is to register a click on a button server-side, not just client-side. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a javascript error stop it from running ?

Comment: Your event handler has no code or have you omitted it, are you certain its not firing?

Comment: @Aristos - You're correct. `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<an HTMLFormElement> is not a function`. I was under the impression that using OnServerClick would not require javascript to function. Is there no way to capture a click on an HTML button without javascript?

Comment: You're in an UpdatePanel, otherwise it wouldn't generate javascript. No way around it for async postback.

Comment: @RandomNoob - Yes, code has been left out and I'm sure it's not firing.

Comment: @jamietre - I'm not in an updatepanel, is there another reason why it might be generating javascript?

Comment: Hmm... that seems awfully strange but maybe that's the way the HtmlButton click event is handled by asp.net. A regular `<asp:Button>` would not produce javascript for a Click event.

Comment: @jamietre - I guess I'll have to work with an asp Button instead but I'm running into different issues with that. That's for another question though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Aristos - Post that as an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @Radu actually i might be wrong about that. Try using asp:Button and try using OnCommand event instead of OnClick. But if there's a need to avoid javascript for some reason you aren't going to get very far with asp.net! :)

Comment: @jamietre - I'm not avoiding js completely, I'd just like this particular function to work with it disabled. If it didn't involve special headers in the response I'd be using jQuery for sure.

Comment: Just do it old-school then - don't have any click event, use a regular html button (no runat=server), and just put logic in Page_Load to handle the postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a javascript error stop it from running...

Well I say that because they only reason that is stop it from working, from the code I see was the javascript error.