# Asp button with different button type

Tags: asp.net, button

Is it possible to have an asp button that isn't rendered with a `type="submit"` tag. I don't want the button to submit the form, so I'd like to have it as `type="button"` instead. Perhaps a better way to phrase my question would be: How do I prevent an asp button from submitting?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just set [`UseSubmitBehavior="false"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior) and it will render `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` (.net 4 at least)

Comment: UseSubmitBehavior is property to chose _which_ submit mechanism (browser or ASP.NET using javascript) to use. **The property does not disable page submit.** For more info see [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In order to prevent pressing the button to submit the form, you can put the button into an UpdatePanel

Answer (score 10):

Using the attribute UseSubmitBehaviour="false" solved my problem

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="just a button" />
```

This attribute is available since .Net v2.0, for more information: [Button.UseSubmitBehavior Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: UseSubmitBehavior is property to chose which submit mechanism (browser or ASP.NET using javascript) to use. The property does not disable page submit.

Comment: In order to prevent pressing the button to submit the form, you can put the button into an UpdatePanel

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

1) Add a OnClientClick property which returns false.

```
 <asp:Button runat="Server" ONClientClick="return true"/>
```

2) Or use a HTML Control i.e:

```
 <input type="button" id="testButton" value="Regular Button" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: In my case, UseSubmitBehavior="false" still refreshed the page. The second option of this answer is working instead.

Comment: UseSubmitBehavior is property to chose _which_ submit mechanism (browser or ASP.NET using javascript) to use. **The property does not disable page submit.** For more info see [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the button to submit, do you need a button at all ? After all, it doesn't do anything before it posts back to the server. You can might as well just use an `<input type="button"`.

That being said, you can use javascript to prevent a postback:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Comment: Not using an html button because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608733/onserverclick-not-working. Is there a way to stop the submit server-side as well?

Comment: "stop the submit server-side" doesn't really make sense. Either you submit or you don't, it's the client (browser) that ultimately decides this. Perhaps give some more context, what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I just had to update a webforms application and I stumbled across this.  The Question is confusing for sure.  I'm not sure why anyone would want to use OnClientClick ...    per the other answers This works for ME , because I have jquery to interact with a button    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" />     Which renders OUT as  type="button" instead of  type="submit"   perfect...

Comment: "If you don't want the button to submit, do you need a button at all ?" - to do other things like open modal popups/dialogs , change values, transform DOM etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent postback when pressing on an `<asp:Button>`

[Check this](http://forums.asp.net/p/929543/1086738.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. btnGrades.**UseSubmitBehavior** = false;
2. btnGrades.**OnClientClick** = "btnGradesClick(this)";
3. js **function** :

   function btnGradesClick(btn) {
   console.log(btn);
   }
4. in chrome : press f12 and see the console tab then click on the button you can see the button tag.