# ASP.net button without submit

Tags: asp.net

Is there ASP button that won't submit post form data.

Whenever I click an asp button it post form data and I want to change that behavior so I can post some other form data I will create it programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript and intercept the `onclick` event, and there you make an Ajax call.

In the event handler, return `false` and your form won't be submitted. Something like this:

```
<script>
    function on_s() {
       /// do some AJAX with JQuery or any other library
       $.ajax({ url: "your_asp_entry.aspx" });
       // you can add some processing to the AJAX call
       return false;
    }
</script>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="return on_s();" />
</form>
</body>
```

On `your_asp_entry.aspx` you do whatever you need to invoke your C# function/method.

Update: changed the answer after OP said on the comments he/she needs to invoke a C# function.

Comment: Yes but then I cannot call any c# functions! I want to disable submit behavior and call a function. Even  UseSubmitBehavior is set to false it still submits.

Comment: @Pinchy: if you need to invoke a C# function you need to do **AJAX** on your Event handler. That's your only choice. Use JQuery or any other JS library to do the AJAX call and invoke the C# function.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on that? Thanks

Comment: @Pinchy: yes. Lot of them. Google: "ASP.NET AJAX".

Answer (score 14):

Using the attribute UseSubmitBehaviour="false" solved my problem

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="just a button" />
```

This attribute is available since .Net v2.0, for more information: [Button.UseSubmitBehavior Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is incorrect.  If UseSubmitBehavior is false, then the button type is changed to ```button```, but the form is still submitted via javascript.  If its true, then the button type is ```submit```.  Either way the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3):

add
 `onclientclick="Javascript:return false;"` to aspbutton

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not in SP2013 and if used in a pop up dialog. This causes the dialog to close. The solution by @Imran Rafique works.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue here is that a `<button>` will submit its parent form by default, unless otherwise specified (e.g. `type="button"`).

Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812667/1146547) that discusses adding the `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` ASP attribute to set the correct type attribute on the button.

And here's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) from MDN that explains the default `type="submit"` type when none is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example button html button without form submit, just use html button with runat="server" and **type="button"**.

```
<input id="butDelete" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" 
value="Delete" OnServerClick="butDelete_ServerClick" onclick="if 
(!confirm('Sure?')) return;"/>
```