# Simulating a button click at onkeyup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events

I have two TextBoxes with corresponding two Buttons. I want that when a TextBox has the focus and the user hits Enter then the corresponding Button's code behind event handler is executed as if it was clicked. This is a sample code:

Aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="myfunction1(event)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button 1" usesubmitbehavior="false" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onkeyup="myfunction2(event)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button 2" usesubmitbehavior="false" />

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction1(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
            document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click();
    }
    function myfunction2(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
            document.getElementById('<%= Button2.ClientID %>').click();
    }
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Button 1 was clicked";
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Button 2 was clicked";
}
```

But when I press Enter in any of the TextBoxes it always executes the `Button1` code behind event handler. If I click on the buttons it obviously works as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: What about keys other than Enter? Enter will submit the form, and asp:buttons render as `<input type="submit" .../>`. Since `Textbox1` is first, it's getting the submit event.

Comment: @bhamlin Yes it works correctly with other keys.

Comment: @bhamlin So the solution would be to not use asp:buttons and in instead use html buttons? Post it and if it is the best solution I will accept.

Comment: Why you just use the TextBox event onChange? no? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Button's `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false` is the simplest solution. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812667/131874) in the [link by @jbabey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4608921/131874).

Answer (score 2):

an ASP button renders as a submit button by default. The default action for Enter `keypress` (happens after `keydown`, before `keyup`) when a form element is in focus is to submit the form. If an HTML form contains multiple submit buttons, the first one is the default submit button.

Putting all this together, when you `keypress` (remember, happens after `keydown`, before `keyup`) with the Enter key, the form is submitted via the default submit button (`Button1`).

You have many options to fix the problem. I would recommend using an `input type="button"` instead of an ASP button with `runat=server` and handle the click events from there.

Related: [Asp button with different button type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608921/asp-button-with-different-button-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by putting the set in a panel control and setting DefaultButton property of the panel

Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1" Height="72px">

   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="myfunction1()"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button 1" />

   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onkeyup="myfunction2()"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button 2" />

</asp:Panel>
```